# sql conversion to mongodb aggregate

Tags: sql, mongodb

I'm new to SQL and MongoDB. I'm trying to convert this:

```
SELECT accountType, ROUND(AVG(balance), 2) avgBalance
FROM customers
WHERE gender="female"
GROUP BY accountType
HAVING COUNT(*) < 140
ORDER BY avgBalance
LIMIT 1
```

to *MongoDB* but I can't get it to work. I don't quite understand how the order ($group, $match, $project, $round, $avg etc.) should be and how the "ROUND and AVG" are used together. This is how the answer should be like: { "accountType" : "account-type", "avgBalance" : NumberDecimal("9999.99") }

Here is what I have so far:

```
db.customers.aggregate( [ { $group: { _id: { accountType: "accountType", avgBalance: { $avg: { "balance" } } }, { $match: { count: { $lt: 140 } } }, { gender: "female" }, { $project: { "accountType": { $round: [ $agv: "balance", 2 ] } } }, { $limit: 1 } ] )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Direction is not bad, would be this one:

```
db.customers.aggregate([
   //  WHERE gender="female"
   { $match: { gender: "female" } },
   // GROUP BY accountType, SELECT AVG(balance)
   {
      $group: {
         _id: "$accountType",
         avgBalance: { $avg: "$balance" },
         count: {$sum: 1}
      }
   },
   // HAVING COUNT(*) < 140
   { $match: { count: { $lt: 140 } } },
   // SELECT ... AS ...
   {
      $project: {
         accountType: "$_id",
         avgBalance: { $round: ["$avgBalance", 2] }
      }
   },
   // ORDER BY avgBalance
   { $sort: { avgBalance: 1 } },
   // LIMIT 1
   { $limit: 1 }
])
```

Comment: Thanks! :-) I modified it a little to give it the right form but the avgBalance gives me "null" and I dont' t know why. Here is the modified mongo:                    db.customers.aggregate([ { $match: { gender: "female" } }, { $group: { _id: "$accountType", avgBalance: { $avg: "$balance" }, count: {$sum: 1} } }, { $match: { count: { $lt: 140 } } }, { $project: { _id: 0, accountType: "$_id", avgBalance: { $round: ["$balance", 2] }}}, { $sort: { avgBalance: 1 } }, { $limit: 1 }])

Comment: Maybe because of this: "balance" : NumberDecimal("3485.90")?

Comment: Please edit your question and put additional code the. Please also provide some sample input data. See my update -> `avgBalance: { $round: ["$avgBalance", 2] }`.

Comment: Thank you for your advise. I didn't notice one could edit the original question. Sorry about that. And thank you for your update, I had tried almost everything that I could think of but not that.